# Creating reminders with complex rules in ios

Tags: ios, eventkit, ekeventkit

I want to create a repeating reminder with a complex rule i.e

1. reminders will have a start date and end date.
2. reminders will repeat on specific week days only.
3. On the selected day between start date and end date they will occur on specific time.

```
- (id)initRecurrenceWithFrequency:(EKRecurrenceFrequency)type interval:(NSInteger)interval daysOfTheWeek:(NSArray *)days daysOfTheMonth:(NSArray *)monthDays monthsOfTheYear:(NSArray *)months weeksOfTheYear:(NSArray *)weeksOfTheYear daysOfTheYear:(NSArray *)daysOfTheYear setPositions:(NSArray *)setPositions end:(EKRecurrenceEnd *)end
```

appeared to be close but as far as i understand the doc i think i will have to use a combination of events.

I need pointers in direction of creating reminders which happen on **specific times of day-> on specific day of week ->within specific start date and end date**

Thank you

**EDIT**

I have tried following things and have faced some problem got some success

```
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:kEVENTSTORE_SINGLTON];
    event.title = @"Event Title test";
    event.notes= @"Hope this one displays";
    NSArray* rulesArray = [event recurrenceRules];
    for (EKRecurrenceRule* rule in rulesArray) [event removeRecurrenceRule:rule];

    event.startDate = [NSDate date]; //today
    event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting
    [event setCalendar:[kEVENTSTORE_SINGLTON defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];



    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    EKAlarm *alarm1 = [EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:[date dateByAddingTimeInterval:60]];
        // [event addAlarm:alarm1];

    EKAlarm *arm=[EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:60];

    EKAlarm *alarm2 = [EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:[date dateByAddingTimeInterval:120]];
        // [event addAlarm:alarm2];


    EKAlarm *alarm3 = [EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:[date dateByAddingTimeInterval:180]];
        //  [event addAlarm:alarm3];

    EKAlarm *alarm4 = [EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:[date dateByAddingTimeInterval:240]];
        //[event addAlarm:alarm4];

    EKRecurrenceRule *objRecurrenceRule=[[EKRecurrenceRule alloc]initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyWeekly interval:1 daysOfTheWeek:@[[EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:EKFriday]] daysOfTheMonth:nil monthsOfTheYear:nil weeksOfTheYear:nil daysOfTheYear:nil setPositions:nil end:[EKRecurrenceEnd recurrenceEndWithOccurrenceCount:1]];


        //[event addRecurrenceRule:objRecurrenceRule];
    event.recurrenceRules=@[objRecurrenceRule];
    event.alarms=@[arm];//if i add the relative alarm it works if i add absolute alarm it dosnt.
    NSError *err = nil;
    [kEVENTSTORE_SINGLTON saveEvent:event span:EKSpanFutureEvents commit:YES error:&err];
    if(err)
        NSLog(@"some error occured");
```

So i observed that recurrence rule works with relative alarm that makes sence becoz if alarm has to occour every Friday whats the point of giving absolute alarm

but my requirement is i want alarm to ring every friday say 5 PM date can be relative but time has to be fixed how can i achieve this?

Comment: do you found any solution for this, Since i am also need to develop the same thing!